# Rendering Devise Gem signup form in My Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

HI guys from past few days I am working on **"ROR"** . I copied Devise Gem Sign UP form ***registrations/new*** > And i added following helper to my

helper/accounts_helper.rb

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

***Views/accounts/new***

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  Email</label></small><%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true , label: false %>   </div>  

 Password</label></small><%= f.password_field :password, label: false %>    </div>  </div>

 Confirm Password</label></small><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation , label: false %>

 f.submit "Sign Up" ,  class: "btn btn-default pull-left"%>
 <= render "devise/shared/links" %>         
<end >
```

Admin will get these form and these should be saved to Devise users tables? Should I do anything in Controller/model??

Comment: This form for registrations only if you want create users you need another form and controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI you can change your devise paths, so you can have your registrations happening in `accounts` rather than `registrations`:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, path: "accounts", path_names: { sign_in: 'login', password: 'forgot', confirmation: 'confirm', unlock: 'unblock', sign_up: new', sign_out: 'logout'}
```

This will create `/accounts/new` for register, and `accounts/login` to login